# Misunderstanding C++ Primer 5th Edition Exercise 1.19 "The If Statement"?

Tags: c++

everyone. In exercise 1.19 of C++ Primer 5th Edition, it says to

```
Revise the program you wrote for the exercises in 1.4.1 (p.
13) that printed a range of numbers so that it handles input in which the first
number is smaller than the second
```

My code seems to meet the requirements when it is run:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter two numbers: " << std::endl;
    int v1 = 0, v2 = 0;
    std::cin >> v1 >> v2;
    if (v1 < v2) {
        while (v1 <= v2) {
            std::cout << v1 << std::endl;
            ++v1;
            }
        }
    else {
        std::cout << "First number is bigger." << std::endl;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Yet when I check two different sites to check my answers, they both have a different statement in the if statement:

```
// Print each number in the range specified by two integers.

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        int val_small = 0, val_big = 0;
        std::cout << "please input two integers:";
        std::cin >> val_small >> val_big;

        if (val_small > val_big)
        {
                int tmp = val_small;
                val_small = val_big;
                val_big = tmp;
        }

        while (val_small <= val_big)
        {
                std::cout << val_small << std::endl;
                ++val_small;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Both answers seem to have a temp int variable, and I am not sure how or why it is more correct for the problem.

Comment: The second example is swapping values.

Comment: Your program prints an error if the numbers are entered in the wrong order. The answers at the other sites swap them to get them into the right order.

Comment: Oh alright. After running the program I was able to see that. Thank you. I just wasn't sure if my answer was considered "wrong" within the context of the exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exercise that is being revised reads:

> Write a program that prompts the user for two integers. Print each number in the range specified by those two integers.

When exercise 1.19 asks you to change the program so that it "handles" input where the first number is smaller, what it means is that the program should still print each number in the range. I also think the exercise is assuming that your earlier version of the program only works if the first number is greater to or equal than the second number.

---

In other words, you need to write a program where the output is the same for both of the following inputs:

> input: 5 10
> output: 5 6 7 8 9 10
>
> input: 10 5
> output: 5 6 7 8 9 10

The example solution you show is achieving this by checking that the input numbers are in a certain order, and if they're not, then it swaps them. This ensures that the two values are in the order expected by the rest of the program.

Answer (score 1):

I guess in the task should be "if the first number is greater than the second" since the other case is already handled in your code whereas this one just prints an error message.

In the example they just swap the values if the first one is greater than the second one.

Answer (score 0):

I tried my version of the code, and it looks like this:

```
//enter code here
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
int main() 
{
//write a program that prompts the user for 2 integers
//  print each number in the range specifies by those 2 integers

int val1 = 0, val2 = 0;
cout << "Enter 2 integer values: ";
cin >> val1 >> val2;
cout << endl;
// my reason for using if is to always make sure the values are in incrementing order
if (val1 > val2)
{
    for (int i = val2; i <= val1; ++i)
        cout << i << " ";
}
else
{
    for (int i = val1; i <= val2; ++i)
        cout << i << " ";
}
cout << endl;
`
```

whether your input is 5 10 or 10 5: your output will always be: 5 6 7 8 9 10.